# Javascript new Date().getTime is before newDate(year, month... )

Tags: javascript, time

I have a strange date issue with Date() in javascript which is causing me havock.

I am quite simply trying to delta the time between new Date() and new Date(2015, 5, 31, 23, 59, 0, 0), and getting very strange results.

This code was run on June 1st 21:51pm.

```
> new Date(2015,05,31).getTime();
< 1435701600000
> new Date().getTime();
< 1433187410175
```

How is is possible that the date for yesterday greater than now ???

Comment: I know this isn't really a solution but have you tried moment.js? I find it really useful to help with dates and date formatting

Comment: Do you realize that is "July 1st 2015"?

Comment: Also notice that the `Date` constructor does take your timezone into account, which you might or might not want (you could use `Date.UTC` instead)

Answer (score 1):

`Date` uses 0-based months.

Your date is actually in June.

Comment: ANd it is not June, it is actually July